# How to investigate routing of firewall issue?

Tags: firewall, routing

SERVERA needs to reach SERVERB.

we cannot ping SERVERB from SERVERA. 
we cannot see any open port for SERVERB from SERVERA.

**Question**: in general, how can we find out, that it is a routing or firewall issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% certain way of knowing a network communication failure is being caused by a firewall, but by going with the rule of elimination, you can come to this conclusion.

1. Make sure you are not running any server based firewalls, likes of `iptables`. Because, if you go to firewall people, they will blame those first, most of the time without doing anything on their end. So, make sure nothing of that sort is running.
2. Make sure your IP address and netmask is properly set up. To make sure about that, try establishing the same connection that you are attempting from server A to server B, between server A and server AA which is in the same subnet as server A. Make sure that, this connection succeeds.
3. Even though it means not much but try running a `traceroute` from Server A to Server B and attach the output to the document/ticket you are sending to firewall folks.
4. If firewall and network operations are not the same group, managed by the same person, it is best to start your investigation with network team. There might be a misconfigured VLAN setting.